# Micro Four Thirds: Which lens adapters are most compatible?

Tags: micro-four-thirds, lens-adapter

Using the micro four thirds (MFT) system allows you to pick from a wide variety of mount adapters which which to attach your old lenses (Nikon F, Canon EF, Pentax K, etc).

Question: Which common lens mount standards are most compatible with a MFT camera using an adapter? Are there some lens mount standards that give you access to the full functionality of the adapted lens on an MFT camera?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, only the four MFT-FT adapters by Panasonic and Olympus offer nearly full compatibility to original FourThirds lenses. I say nearly, because some FourThirds lenses are not compatible with all MFT cameras. E,.g. some old FT lenses are not compatible with the contrast AF. And SWD lenses generally perform not so well on MFT. And the aperture ring on the Panasonic/Leica FT lenses works only on Panasonic FT/MFT bodies.
There was a compatibility list on the Panasonic website, but I was unable to find it now.
The current adapters to all other mounts are non-electronic and allow you only to focus manually.
Those FourThirds to MircoFourThirds adapters allow for autofocus, however check the compatibility for every camera/lens combination:

```
Panasonic 
 DMW-MA1 (metal) 
Olympus
 MMF-1 (metal)
 MMF-2 (plastic)
 MMF-3 (weather sealed)
```

Comment: Is it correct that no MFT-FT's allow you to use autofocus?

Comment: No, there are currently 4 adapters which allow autofocus with FT lenses. However, not all FT lenses are supported by all cameras and all SWD lenses do not perform well on MFT cameras. They are slow to autofocus.
`
Panasonic
DMW-MA1 (metal)
Olympus
MMF-1 (metal)
MMF-2 (plastic)
MMF-3 (weather sealed))
`