# Which lens adapter will I need to mount a Olympus Zuiko 35mm lens to Panasonic DMC-GF3 camera?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, micro-four-thirds, four-thirds

I have a Panasonic DMC-GF3 camera body. I intend to buy a used Olympus Zuiko 35mm f/3.5 ED Macro Lens.

What adapter will I require?

Comment: thank you for your answer, do I assume that the Brand of lens is therefore not relevant to the choice of adapter?

Comment: Correct, at least for the most part. You'll have to research amongst the specific adapters you're considering. There might be a minor feature difference, firmware issue, cost, etc., that will go into your consideration. But mainly, it's the mount format that matters more than anything.

Comment: See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000). The answer is different if the Zuiko 35mm lens you want to adapt is a film-era OM-mount lens. :)

Answer (score 2):

The lens is for a Four-Thirds mount camera. Your Panasonic is a Micro Four-Thirds (MFT) mount camera. Thus, you will need a Four-Thirds to Micro Four-Thirds adapter.

Related questions:

- [Micro four thirds lens and camera compatibility](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27612/micro-four-thirds-lens-and-camera-compatibility/27614#27614)
- [Does Pentax make a lens adapter to fit Olympus lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/does-pentax-make-a-lens-adapter-to-fit-olympus-lenses/72198#72198)
- [Micro Four Thirds: Which lens adapters are most compatible?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/micro-four-thirds-which-lens-adapters-are-most-compatible)

Other Resources:

- [Four Thirds to Micro FT adapters](https://www.apotelyt.com/photo-accessory/four-thirds-adapter) at ApoTelyt.com